# Is re a prefix in respect?

Tags: prefixes

Is re a prefix in respect or just a part of the word? Any guidance on this would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Not in English, but it is derived from the Latin verb *respicio*, in which *re-* seems ultimately to have been a prefix.

Comment: Similarly *despicio* despise: the Latin can be divided, but not the English.

Answer (score -1):

No, *re-* is not considered a prefix in *respect*. Compare the Online Etymology Dictionary entries for [*respect*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=respect&searchmode=none) and [*disrespect*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=disrespect&searchmode=none). *Dis-* is a prefix added to *respect* to form the word *disrespect.* As Barrie notes, at one time in its history, the *re*- in *respect's* predecessors might have been considered a prefix.

> **respect** (v.) 1540s, "to regard," from Middle French *respecter* "look back; respect; delay," from Latin *respectere*, frequentative of *respicere*
>
> **disrespect** 1610s (v.), 1630s (n.), from *dis*- + *respect*.

Comment: Clearly, however, they **are** prefixes. They're surely not suffixes or infixes. _Re-_ is a productive prefix in English, though it's pretty frozen into _respect_; what's being asked about is the temperature of the freeze. That's an empirical matter, and until there are measurements, it's irresponsible to say that they're not prefixes, just because somebody says so. Nobody knows what standards or rules they're following, and everyone's mileage varies.

Comment: @JohnLawler You say "they are prefixes" ...? What are? I'm not sure what you are referring to. I said *dis-* is a prefix. I would argue that re-  in *respect* is not a prefix in modern English. Even Barrie said so.

Comment: _Re-_ and _dis-_ are productive prefixes in English. _Dis_ has even escaped morphological captivity to become a verb.